# How to change NSTextField background color in NSPopOver

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

[image]

Mac OSX 10.10 Xcode 6.1

I created a tableview in NSPopOver. 
I try to change textfield's background color. Why? no effect.
The tableview's highlight set to "regular". 
which way can let me change textfields background color to white?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a known bug with text fields and the "vibrancy" blending added in Yosemite. It's known to affect popovers.

The workaround is to set the `appearance` property of the table view to `NSAppearanceNameAqua`.

This was [confirmed](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1104658#1104658) by an Apple engineer in their devforums.

**2019-05-09 EDIT:**

This issue also sometimes affects NSTextFields that appear on popovers where the background is grey. Here's the Swift 5 fix, add this to the viewDidLoad() function of your popover controller

self.someTextField.appearance = NSAppearance.init(named: .aqua)

Comment: Priceless answer. It applies to any other view. It was driving me crazy. Thank you Ken

Comment: I'm on 10.12 and unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me. I'm having the same kind of problem but in a custom NSMenu, which I think internal is still displayed as popover (but I'm 100% sure about that). For each item of the menu (NSMenuItem) I'm setting my custom view with item.view = X, then I have an NSTextField added on top of X. The text field is perfectly displayed when I do not draw any background in drawRect of X, instead there's always this weird color when I draw a background (essentially when the item is highlighted).

Answer (score 12):

In my app, I had same problem. I used Swift and this worked for me. In your viewForTableColumn:

```
let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn!.identifier!, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
    cell.textField?.drawsBackground = true
    cell.textField?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: The text field background color can also be set clear in the nib.

Answer (score 1):

I really like @Prontto's solution but it does not work with `NSImageView` because it has no `drawsBackground` or `backgroundColor`.

Fortunately the appearance option works for image views as well!

```
cell.imageView?.image = image ?? nil
cell.imageView?.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameAqua)
```

Comment: My table cell view has an image view and a text field, and I was only seeing the gray background on the text field.