# Avoid OSX glassy background effect on NSPredicateEditor

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, custom-view

In my application (OSX, Objective-C, XCode 8.2, ARC) i have a popover. The popover's view has a custom class with white background. In the view i placed an NSPredicateEditor. If i open the popover, i can see the "glassy" effect on the text "of the following is true". I have that behaviour at other places with the same custom NSView. How can i avoid that? So that there's just the regular background?

[image]

This is the custom view code implementation:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
[[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
[super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to change NSTextField background color in NSPopOver](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29074724/4244136).

Comment: That did it! Thank you.