# NSTextField setBackgroundColor makes both fields the latter color setting?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextfield

2 TextFields are created to be 2 different backgrounds.  But both are colored "yellow" instead of "blue" and "yellow" ?
In fact, if I switch the 2 items, the last one is the one both items are colored.

```
NSTextField *tfRange = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,10, 100, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:tfRange];
[tfRange setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
[tfRange setStringValue:@"0"];
[tfRange setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:40] ];
[tfRange setTag:10001];

NSTextField *tfOffset = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,60, 100, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:tfOffset];
[tfOffset setBackgroundColor:[NSColor yellowColor]];
[tfOffset setStringValue:@"7"];
[tfOffset setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:40] ];
[tfOffset setTag:10000];
```

The numbers display correctly... 0 and 7

Comment: At present your code sets the string value for both fields to `@"0"`.  If you set them both to different strings, do you get different strings appearing in each field?  If you add the line `NSLog(@"%@, %@", tfRange, tfOffset);` at the end of that code, what output gets logged?

Comment: @SonofaBeach - The behaviour the OP reports can also be observed if the two (or more) fields are defined in IB and not programmatically. The issue is not related to the OP's code *per se*.

Comment: Maybe related: [How to change NSTextField background color in NSPopOver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29075294/4244136).

Comment: added more:  0 and 7 show fine.