# nspopover viewcontroller optical issue

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, nspopover

i put a view controller into my storyboard and include an ABPeoplePickerViewer. now i press a button in my main view controller, which opens the nspopover.

this looks like this:
[image]

the right side shows my contacts - but i censored it with red view.
but you can see the problem on this picture.

left side > my groups, which all haves a light gray background.
same with the label left of the search field (448 Karten)+
why do they have this light gray background color?

Comment: Same problem: [How to change NSTextField background color in NSPopOver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074724/how-to-change-nstextfield-background-color-in-nspopover).

Comment: thank you very much. this helps a lot :)